# How to convert many HTML files to MediaWiki Pages on Windows?

Tags: html, windows, converters, mediawiki

I'm on Windows and I have an `index.html` in a folder and a huge set of html pages in subfolders.

How can I convert these html files to MediaWiki pages?

Comment: did you check https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_external_content#Converting_content_from_HTML_text_file?

Comment: There is a no GUI tool has been mentioned in the link. Need to go through the dependencies and verify the same. Do we have any GUI tool to do the same?

Comment: @KathiresanJeyapandian: Why would you need a GUI tool? Is there any interactivity required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Converting content from HTML text file](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_external_content#Converting_content_from_HTML_text_file) section from the manual at mediawiki.org. Personally I would start with these two, and if that doesn't work I'd build something based on [pywikibot](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot). Any of these solutions can be made to work on Windows, though it is advisable to try it on Linux or OS X first, and if not install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

You're unlikely to find any kind of streamlined GUI tool for such a specialized action. If you need more help with using the code available there you should hire a programmer or learn how to do it yourself.